# What does the @EJBs annotation do?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I know roughly what this construction does:  it creates a SomeType EJB and injects the object into another EJB.

```
 @EJB(name="name1")
 SomeType someVariable
```

Now I have a class which starts like this: (I give all class-level annotations, even though I think only the `@EJBs` is relevant)

```
@Remote(SomeClass.class)
@Stateless(name="someName")
@EJBs({@EJB(name="name1",beanInterface=Type1.class),
       @EJB(name="name2",beanInterface=Type2.class)})
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class X extends Y{ 
  //code
```

What do the `@EJB` s do here? They probably get or create the "name1" ... objects from JNDI, but where do they put the result?  I don't see a `.lookup` call anywhere near, but the codebase is huge so I'm not very sure about this.

Bonus question: I presume the two `@Transaction` annotations simply repeat defaults?

*UPDATE:* Multiple persons claimed at this point that `@EJBs` is a proprietary extension.  It is not. It is a core part of java EE5. See [the JavaDoc for details.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/EJBs.html).  It is simply a container for the individual `@EJB` annotations.

I believe everyone who claims these EJB annotations do a lookup.  I just want to know what happens with the result of this lookup.

Comment: Well this is weird I have never heard of `@EJBs` and ussage like this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `@EJB` annotation (and `@Resource`, `@WebServiceRef`, etc.) serves two purposes:

1. It declares a reference in the component namespace.  For example, `@EJB(name="myEJB")` creates a reference `java:comp/env/myEJB`.  If you annotate a field and do not specify a name, then it creates a reference `java:comp/env/com.example.MyClass/myField`.
2. If the annotation is declared on a field or setter method, then the container performs injection when the component is created.

How the reference is resolved varies, independent of whether the reference is being resolved for a `lookup("java:comp/env/myEJB")` or due to injection:

1. If EE 6+ is used, the `lookup` attribute requires a JNDI lookup to resolve the target.
2. Some application servers support `mappedName`, which is specified to be vendor specific.  This is usually implemented by performing a lookup.
3. Application servers support bindings at deployment time.  This is usually implemented by performing a lookup.
4. If no other binding information is provided and the bean interface (`beanInterface` or the field type) is only implemented by a single EJB in the application, then the EJB specification requires that it fall back to that.
5. If no other binding information is provided and #4 cannot work, some application servers will attempt to perform a lookup in the server namespace based on the ref name (for example, `java:comp/env/myEJB` might cause a lookup of `myEJB` in the server namespace).

Comment: I had a web project, jee 6, with ejbs in it and i didnt have to specify name attribute with @EJB, once I moved ejbs to separate ejb jar (still same ear) weblogic 12.1.2 tells me "The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target Bean has not been specified"

Answer (score 2):

According to this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/545547/EJB-JEE/java/EJBs-annotation), basically this annotation enables EJB to lookup external EJBs relatively to its context. Usually, there are more elegant ways to do that.

Comment: EJBs is part of the Java EE5 standard. See the javadoc here as proof.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/ejb/javadoc-3_0-fr/index.html?javax/ejb/EJBs.html.  This javadoc is clear enough: It simply gathers multiple EJB annotations.   I think you are correct in saying these EJBs lookup.  The main part of my queistion is: where is the result of this lookup stored?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, had no idea that this is included in standard, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Miljen Mikic's answer gave me an idea about the possible answer.  If anyone who knows about JNDI reads this, please tell me if this is sane, as I'm basically guessing here.

Basically, there are 2 ways to look into the JNDI tree: either via a global path  (/some/proprietary/path/my/bean) and via your program's environment (java:comp/env/my/bean).  The idea is that you create references from the global path to you local environment, and then lookup the components from there.

So @Ejb(name="java:comp/env/my/bean",mappedName="/some/proprietary/path/my/bean") would create this reference from java code (without descriptor xml file).

This means @Ejb(name="java:comp/env/my/bean") is on its own a no-op: It copies a reference onto itself.  It might hava as side effect the fact that you application server now knows at compile time that this reference is required,but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

As for the bonus question: Yes, the two annotations regarding transactions are repeating defaults: The default TransactionManagementType is CONTAINER (vs BEAN) and the - default - TransactionAttributeType REQUIRED simply states that if the bean is called within a transactional context the transaction is continued, otherwise a new transaction will be initiated (as opposed to, for example REQUIRES_NEW which will always create a new tx). This is actually in detail not as trivial as it sounds Cf. the EJB 3.1 spec:

"13.3.7 Specification of the Transaction Attributes for a Bean’s Methods

The Bean Provider of an enterprise bean with container-managed transaction demarcation may specify
the transaction attributes for the enterprise bean’s methods. By default, the value of the transaction
attribute for a method of a bean with container-managed transaction demarcation is the REQUIRED
transaction attribute, and the transaction attribute does not need to be explicitly specified in this case.[...]"