# GlassFish error: javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean user

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-3

When I starting my glassfish application server, I see the following error:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean user
root cause

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean user
root cause

com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name,Remote 3.x interface =java.lang.String,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.lang.String,refType=Session into class com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name,Remote 3.x interface =java.lang.String,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.lang.String,refType=Session into class com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name,Remote 3.x interface =java.lang.String,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.lang.String,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'java.lang.String#java.lang.String' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java.lang.String#java.lang.String' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.lang.String#java.lang.String not found]]]
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.tsystems.demail.Beans.User/first_name,Remote 3.x interface =java.lang.String,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=java.lang.String,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'java.lang.String#java.lang.String' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java.lang.String#java.lang.String' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.lang.String#java.lang.String not found]]
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java.lang.String#java.lang.String' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.lang.String#java.lang.String not found]
root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.lang.String#java.lang.String not found
```

In stacktrace I see the following error:

```
[#|2013-07-01T23:53:14.447+0400|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=100;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java.lang.String#java.lang.String not found
```

Part of my bean class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User {

    public static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");

    @EJB
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String mobile_phone;
    private String password;
    private String rtPassword;
    private Date birth_day;
    private String username;
    private List data;
    private Map<String,Object> userList;
    private String temp;
    private UIComponent phoneLogin;
    private UIComponent profileReg;
    .....
    //logic with methods
```

How to fix it? Please help.

Comment: you're marking `String first_name` with [`@EJB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html). You're not injecting an EJB, so remove the annotation.

Comment: @damo 5 minutes before, I was having EJB annotation without error. Magic :D
Answer to my post and I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private String first_name;` is not an EJB, but you are marking it with the [`@EJB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) annotation. Remove the annotation and the error should go away. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348542/what-does-the-ejbs-annotation-do) for more information about what the annotation is doing.