# Local session bean JNDI lookup in WebLogic - NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, jndi

I am not able to lookup local session beans from within an EJB module in WebLogic 10.3.6.

In the following example I *could* use injection, but in the actual product we will need to access local session beans from non-managed objects, so this is for demonstration of the problem. I also know it'll work with a remote interface, but why since I should be able to do it locally.

```
@Local
public interface MyBeanLocal {

    public void foo();

}

@Stateless(name = "MyBean")
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal {

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo");      
    }

}
```

Here the client tries to look up the local session bean. This very same code seems to work in other application servers, but not in WebLogic.

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerInbound implements CustomerInboundLocal {

    @Override
    public void someOperation() throws Exception {

        try {

            // Exception is thrown here when looking up the object
            MyBeanLocal testLocal = (MyBeanLocal) 
                    new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/MyBean");

            testLocal.foo();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/MyBean in /app/ejb/test-inject#CustomerInbound.; remaining name 'comp/env/MyBean'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:412)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.AbstractURLContext.lookup(AbstractURLContext.java:130)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at beans.CustomerInbound.someOperation(CustomerInbound.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.someOperation(Unknown Source)
    at beans.CustomerInbound_xaxie8_CustomerInboundLocalImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:39)
    at beans.CustomerInbound_xaxie8_CustomerInboundLocalImpl.someOperation(Unknown Source)
    at beans.CustomerWSFacade.customerIn(CustomerWSFacade.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.customerIn(Unknown Source)
    at beans.CustomerWSFacade_jg1q6w_WSOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.WSOMethodInvoker.invoke(WSOMethodInvoker.java:22)
    at beans.CustomerWSFacade_jg1q6w_WSOImpl.__WL_customerIn_WS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.wsee.server.ejb.WsEjb.invoke(WsEjb.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSEjbInstanceResolver$WLSEjbInvoker.invoke(WLSEjbInstanceResolver.java:192)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.invoke(EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:140)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare a reference to the EJB in order to look it up from `java:comp`.  You can either use the `@EJB` annotation (with or without injection, see [What does the @EJB annotation do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12390108/142446)), or you can declare the reference in web.xml using `<ejb-ref>`.

Otherwise, if you were using a newer version of WebLogic that supported EE 6, you could use the portable `java:global`, `java:app`, or `java:module` namespaces in order to look up the EJB directly, but since WebLogic 10.3.6 only supports EE 5, you would need to use the configured binding name of the EJB.

Comment: I have to do it within the EJB module so I will not be able to use web.xml. I tried to apply the `@EJB` to my session bean but I am getting the same error when trying to lookup the bean, following the link instructions. Can you demonstrate how the `@EJB` values should be set, and how the lookup string should be specified accordingly?

Comment: @BonanzaOne I don't understand since CustomerInbound is annotated `@WebService`, which is only meaningful within a web module.  Can you clarify?  Can you show more stack from the lookup failure (so I can see which container is invoking CustomerInbound)?  Can you show the `@EJB` annotation you tried adding to CustomerInbound?

Comment: Don't worry about the `@WebService`, I created it for test only. I removed it from the code to avoid further confusion. It does work and in fact it does in many other server vendors, web module is not required (maybe it is created under the hood).

Comment: Updated the trace. I am using this example just to simulate, I tried to explain it at the beginning. I have to lookup the EJB manually, not using @EJB, because in my real app I need to do it within a non-managed class (such as a web service handler), injection do not work within those objects and I need to use lookup (I think).

Comment: I was not able to make it work unless I publish it as a remote interface.